# Send XML via WebClient Post using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webclient, memorystream

I am trying to send an XML file that I created in my memorystream. The problem comes in when I try to use `UploadFile` and get the error of Invalid Arguments. My question is, is there anyway I can use my memorystream that I created with `WebClient.UploadFile` to send the file or do I need to do this some other way?

```
string firstname = Request.Headers["firstname"].ToString();
string lastname = Request.Headers["lastname"].ToString();
string organization = Request.Headers["organization"].ToString();
string phone = Request.Headers["phone"].ToString();

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
{
    xml.WriteStartDocument();
    xml.WriteStartElement("List");
    xml.WriteWhitespace("\n");

    xml.WriteStartElement("Employee");
    {
        xml.WriteElementString("First", firstname);
        xml.WriteElementString("Last", lastname);
        xml.WriteWhitespace("\n");
        xml.WriteElementString("Organization", organization);
        xml.WriteElementString("Phone", phone);
    }

    xml.WriteEndElement();
    xml.WriteEndDocument();
}

WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.UploadFile("http://test.com/test.aspx", ms);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Edited in 2013 as it looks like it was entirely wrong back when I originally answered...

Options:

- Take the byte array from the `MemoryStream` and use `UploadData`

  ```
  client.UploadData("http://test.com/test.aspx", ms.ToArray());
  ```
- Use `OpenWrite` instead, and write to the stream returned

  ```
  using (var stream = client.OpenWrite("http://test.com/test.aspx"))
  {
      using (XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
      {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```
- Write the data to a file and then use `UploadFile`

  ```
  using (XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create("tmp.xml", settings))
  {
      ...
  }
  client.UploadFile("http://test.com/test.aspx", "tmp.xml");
  // Delete temporary file afterwards
  ```

I'd personally go for one of the first two approaches, to avoid the temporary file.

Comment: I just don't understand how this works at all.  Where is the `UploadFile` overload defined that allows one to use a stream as the second parameter?  Is it an extension method?

Comment: I agree with Jim, UploadData method has the required signature but it sends raw data.

Comment: @too: You're right, and I'm not sure why I didn't see Jim's comment before. Will edit.

Comment: I've tried these methods and others and I consistently get message from the server telling me its an invalid type. I've attempted adding content-type headers and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: @user1040975: Without knowing more about the server, it's pretty much impossible to help you further.

Comment: I've updated an answer to show my work and created a new question if you're feeling froggy.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215257/attempting-to-post-xml-file-to-mvc-restful-api-and-de-serialize-into-c-sharp-cla

Answer (score 6):

Per your `Invalid Arguments`:

I don't see any method on [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) supports a `MemoryStream`.  Convert your `MemoryStream` to a `String` and use [WebClient.UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstring.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same. I've tried using several of the possible solutions, but with no success.

When I try to use the following method the api gets the request as the string filename has the correct value, but the content of the request object is null...

```
using (FileStream src = System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\XML\OrderXML.txt", FileMode.Open))
            {
                src.CopyTo(ms);
            }

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "Encoding.UTF8";
                //wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = ms.Length.ToString();                    
                wc.UploadString(sURL, ms.ToString());
            }
```

my RESTful API MVC controller:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async void CreateJob(string filename)
    {
        string success = "false";
        try
        {
            //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load
            XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PdnaXmlParse));
            Stream reqStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            PdnaXmlParse res = (PdnaXmlParse)xmls.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(reqStream));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
}
```