# Attempting to post XML file to MVC RESTful API and de-serialize into c# class

Tags: c#, xml, rest, model-view-controller

The front end seems to post fine and my routing seems to be working as my API seems to get the request and the filename is valid. However, when I attempt `await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();` it doesn't seem to read anything and I get a

`Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

exception when de-serializing...

Been at this for awhile trying the different solutions available with no success.. please help.

Things I've tried:

- Different content-types
- Different webclient methods to upload (uploadstring, uploadfile, uploaddata)
- Using WebRequest instead of webclient (I will consistently get an unsupported media type message as a response)

My code:

```
public string CreateJob()
    {
        string test = "";
        string sURL = "http://" + _domain + _apiRoot + "CreateJob/OrderXML";


        try
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();

            using (FileStream src = System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\XML\PageDNAOrderXML.txt", FileMode.Open))
            {
                src.CopyTo(ms);
            }

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "Encoding.UTF8";
                //wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = ms.Length.ToString();                    
                wc.UploadString(sURL, ms.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            test = ex.Message;

        }
        return test;
    }
```

RESTful API

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async void CreateJob(string filename)
    {
        string success = "false";
        try
        {
            //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load
            XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PdnaXmlParse));
            Stream reqStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            PdnaXmlParse res = (PdnaXmlParse)xmls.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(reqStream));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `MemoryStream.ToString()`, which will just return `"System.IO.MemoryStream"` regardless of the content of the stream. You should just upload the binary data directly. Just use `File.ReadAllBytes`, and then `WebClient.UploadData`. Or you *could* use `WebClient.UploadString`, but use `FIle.ReadAllText` first...

Comment: gosh now I feel goofy. Even after hitting that break-point as many times I still didn't see that... now I'm getting an error from within the xml, but at least its getting over to the api now (<Envelope xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> was not expected.). Thanks a bunch

Comment: Whats weird about this is when I watch what returns from new XmlTextReader(reqStream), I get "{None}" for the value, why is that?

Comment: Well presumably because you haven't called `Read()` on the `XmlTextReader`.

Comment: Ended up using uploadData instead, but this method did the trick. I am currently working on getting a [frombody] attribute to work so I don't have to deserialize